# VBA is only running on "Save" but not on "Save As"

Tags: excel, vba

I want to import the name of the excel workbook to particular sets of cells. The function `Display_File_Name` does the trick.

The following code works when I do Save (Ctrl+S) but it doesn't work when I do Save As. I don't see filename getting updated in the cells. How can the function be run even when the user choose to do Save As?

My current workaround is using `Workbook_BeforeClose` or `Workbook_AfterSave` but this will prompt for saving action, which I want to avoid.

Could you help me with this?

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    Call Display_File_Name
    
End Sub

Function Display_File_Name()

    'Import filename
    Set OpenBook = ActiveWorkbook
    
    Filename = OpenBook.Name
    'Record filename on Print page
    OpenBook.Worksheets(4).Range("A2") = Filename
    'Find the last row with values
    LR= OpenBook.Worksheets(6).Columns("B").Find("*", _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
    'Record filename
    OpenBook.Worksheets(6).Range("A2:A" & LR) = Filename

End Function
```

References used:

For `Workbook_BeforeSave`: [Link](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/run-vba-code-on-save.976957/) [Link](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/auto-run-macro-when-saving.528183/)

For `Workbook_BeforeClose`: [Link](https://www.exceltip.com/events-in-vba/how-to-run-a-macro-automatically-before-workbook-close-in-excel.html)

Comment: `BeforeSave` examines the workbook before it is saved, so naturally it sees the old name?

Comment: I'm confused because this code works when I do just save. Should I change my approach? What do you think I should do to avoid endless save prompting?

Comment: How does it work when you just save? The name does not change, so the content of the cell shouldn't change either.

Comment: Oh! I see! I got your 1st comment now. With that said, I want to update the filename information in those cells when filename is changed (i.e. save as). Is there a robust way to go about this other than making a button for people to click?

Comment: Why would `Workbook_AfterSave` be "prompting for saving action", but `Workbook_BeforeSave` wouldn't? They both work whenever a save happens, so `AfterSave` is no more prompting than `BeforeSave`.

Comment: Right. Maybe I shouldn't tie this function to save function. But then what's a good way to make sure the filename is correctly reflected in the workbook?

Comment: By using `Workbook_AfterSave` instead of `Workbook_BeforeSave` (and `Workbook_Open` in case the file name was changed outside Excel)? If `Workbook_BeforeSave` has been perfectly acceptable to you then why would `Workbook_AfterSave` be different?

Comment: Actually I haven't implemented the workbook yet, so I'm not sure how it'll work once people start using them. I wanted to proactively troubleshoot, but I might just let the chips fall on their own. Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 2):

### Update Workbook Before Saving

**Tips**

- `Option Explicit` forces you to declare all variables. Read about its benefits.
- The `Call` keyword is considered deprecated. There is really no use of it.
- `DisplayFileName` is the preferred variable and procedure naming convention in VBA. `Display_File_Name` is kind of reserved for `Classes`.
- To reference the workbook containing this code, in the `ThisWorkbook` module you can use the `Me` keyword. Anywhere else you will use `ThisWorkbook`.
- Although using `Function` works, your procedure should use `Sub` because it only **does**. It **doesn't return** anything like a function does. Consider the following simple example:

  ```
  ' Returns the upper-case version of a string. 
  Function GetUCase(ByVal S As String) As String
      GetUCase = UCase(S)
  End Function
  ```

  It can be utilized with:

  ```
  Sub Test() ' Prints a string and its upper-case version. 
      Const sOld As String = "small"
      Dim sNew As String: sNew = GetUCase(sOld)
      Debug.Print sOld & ", " & sNew ' prints 'small, SMALL'
  End Sub
  ```
- Although you are allowed to 'borrow' some of the `VBA`'s keywords, it is best avoided. You have used the exact casing in `Filename` which is the first argument name of the `SaveAs` or `SaveCopyAs` methods, but it conflicts with the variable naming convention (`FileName`).
- To avoid some surprises (not in this case though), I prefer using `Value` when writing a value to a range e.g. `ws.Range("A1").Value = 1`.
- In the `Find` method, you are unnecessarily using the `SearchOrder` argument while you are searching in one column. The `xlValues` parameter of the `LookIn` argument will fail if there are hidden cells (rows or columns), so I prefer the `xlFormulas` parameter for finding a cell containing anything, which will also find a cell containing a formula evaluating to `""`. If the `Find` method in your code doesn't find a cell, an error will occur. See the code below how this is avoided.
- I haven't fixed the worksheet referencing by using indexes since I don't know the worksheet names, but you should most definitely abandon this way of referencing worksheets.

  - When using indexes e.g. `Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)`, a user could move the tab to another position and your code would fail.
  - Less likely, when using worksheet names e.g. `Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")`, a user could rename the worksheet, and again, the code would fail.
  - Least likely, if you use the code names e.g. `Set ws = Sheet1` or just use `Sheet1` instead of the variable, a user could rename the code name and the code would fail.

**The Code**

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

- Alternatively, you can leave it in the `ThisWorkbook` module.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DisplayFileName(ByVal wb As Workbook)
    
    ' Validate the workbook ('wb').
    If wb Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Write the file name to a variable ('sFileName').
    Dim sFileName As String: sFileName = wb.Name
    
    ' Create a reference to the Print worksheet ('pws').
    Dim pws As Worksheet: Set pws = wb.Worksheets(4)
    ' Create a reference to the Print cell ('pCell').
    Dim pCell As Range: Set pCell = pws.Range("A2")
    ' Write the file name to the Print cell.
    pCell.Value = sFileName
    ' Autofit Print column.
    'pCell.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    
    ' Create a reference to the Destination worksheet ('dws').
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(6)
    
    ' Create a reference to the Destination last cell ('dlCell') in column 'B'.
    Dim dlCell As Range
    Set dlCell = dws.Columns("B").Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
    ' Validate Destination last cell.
    If dlCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' empty 'B' column
    
    ' Write the last row to a variable ('dlRow').
    Dim dlRow As Long: dlRow = dlCell.Row
    ' Validate the last row.
    If dlRow < 2 Then Exit Sub ' the last row cannot be 1 because of '"A2:A"'.
    
    ' Create a reference to the Destination range ('drg') in column 'A'.
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range("A2:A" & dlRow)
    ' Write the file name to the cells of the Destination range.
    drg.Value = sFileName
    ' Autofit Destination column.
    'drg.EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub
```

**`ThisWorkbook` module**

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    DisplayFileName Me
End Sub
```